# How to solve persistence.xml problem with child module?

Tags: java, maven, jpa, persistence, persistence.xml

I have created a project using maven. I have also created two child modules of this project. The structure is like this :

--parentModule
  --childModule-backend
  --childModule-frontend

The application server i have is wildfly 12. I have defined the datasource in the application server. The backend module contains the persistence.xml file. To use the backend module inside the frontend module I have declared it as a dependency in the pom file. The problem is that the war file requires the persistence.xml file and the application is not started successfully. The following exception is thrown :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYWELD0037: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named 'org.jbpm.domain' in deployment child-module-frontend.war
```

If I define the persistence.xml file under /resources/META-INF folder everything works. Can someone help me?. I dont want to have persistence.xml file in both modules. I want to have it only in the backend module

Comment: Is the backend persistence.xml file in the META-INF directory of the jar?

Comment: Yes Steve it is

Comment: So it works if the persistence.xml is in the `resources/META-INF` directory of the backend module?

Comment: No.I must also include it in the resources/META-INF of the frontend module to work

Comment: Is there a persistence.xml in the `src/main/resources/META-INF` directory of your backend module?

Comment: YES it is. To work it must be at both modules. If I only define it to backend module it doenst work

Comment: Please list all the jars that Maven adds to the WEB-INF/lib directory of your frontend module.